# What is the meaning of "He created" in Al-Falaq?

Tags: quran, tafseer

I imagine this question has been asked many times before in history however I could not find sufficient answers on the internet. Al-Falaq says:

> Say, "I seek refuge in the Lord of daybreak;
> From the evil of that which He created".
>
> [Al-Falaq](https://quran.com/113)

What is the meaning of "He created" in Al-Falaq in respect to evil? Why is the verse expressed in a manner that gives the impression in the English language God created evil?

Comment: The verse clearly states: "From the evil **of that** which He created" , there is no individual except that he was created by Allah. So what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

God *did* create all beings and all events. In that verse, we are seeking refuge from the evil that comes from the beings and things God created.

Allah says:

> Allah is the Creator of all things, and He is, over all things, Disposer of affairs. (39:62)

In the verse:

> From the evil of [i.e. coming from] that [i.e. the beings and things] which He created".

Comment: thank you for your assistance. I now think the verse means "the evil coming from beings who don't realise He created them [and will judge them]". In other words, the evil coming from non-believers. Kind regards.

Comment: @Dhammadhatu I am not sure why you felt the need to add "who don't realise He created them." Evil can equally come from beings who know God created them.

Comment: Thank you and I agree. However, I think evil comes from believers when they are not mindful or have a lapse of belief. I think when your faith is strong & cognizant, you will not do evil. Thank you again. The subtle aspects of our discussion here is not important to me. What is important to me is I understand the basic verse and understand it does not mean God creates evil. Kind regards. I have always liked this verse, particularly the: "I seek refuge in the Lord of Daybreak".

Comment: @Dhammadhatu As for whether God creates evil, you may want to ask another question for that. Evil is a part of creation. If God didn't create evil, that would mean evil is uncreated which is obviously wrong. You can see some information here: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/124504/evil-is-part-of-the-creation-of-allaah-and-not-attributing-it-to-allaah-is-part-of-proper-verbal-etiquette

Comment: OK. Thank you again. I will read it.